# Xcode Create xls file, but failed to open on IPAD

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, csv, xls

I have created xls file using this library,

https://github.com/andreac/RSSheet/tree/a3a1c3f9802e67508a773399007ffb9ebf8135c6

But I only can open the created xls file on PC or MAC and I cannot open it on IPAD using any software.

My client want to open it on IPAD, I tried .CSV, and it can be open on any device.

But I cannot create Multiple sheet in .CSV.

I spent too much time on this.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a free app for Microsoft Excel available on the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem using external library xlslib for creating Excel file.
Here is the link.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/